# Pivot display only part of the header after font resize

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I've changed the default style of the Pivot control:

```
<PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="StaticHeader" Height="200" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
               <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                         <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform"/>
                         <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderOffsetTranslateTransform"/>
                     </TransformGroup>
         </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
</PivotHeaderPanel>
```

and set my header by:

```
<PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Height="77"  FontSize="51">Mouse Support</TextBlock>
</PivotItem.Header>
```

but the title isnt displayed properly:
[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Give TextBlock height auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that by default, `PivotHeaderItem`'s height is set to **48**, when the `TextBlock`'s height is larger than 48, it will display only part of it.

To find this, you can use **[Live Visual Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx)** in Visual Studio. When you choose `PivotHeaderItem` in Live Visual Tree and look at the **Live Properties**, you will find it has a default style in which `Height` is set to `48`.
[image]

And you can find the default style at [PivotHeaderItem styles and templates](http://PivotHeaderItem%20styles%20and%20templates).

To fix this issue, you can just add following code in your `Page.Resources` to set the `PivotHeaderItem`'s height to auto. And there is no need to change the default style of the Pivot control.

```
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for response, this solution works very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Give TextBlock `height=auto`, and you have also mentioned PivotHeaderPanel height also. That also might be causing problem. Give the sufficient height or give `Height=Auto`


 <PivotItem.Header>
      <TextBlock Height="Auto "  FontSize="51">Mouse Support</TextBlock>
 </PivotItem.Header>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete XAML containing pivot control?

Comment: This is one of Microsoft [examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPivot) with minor adjustemnts. To find explanation just read @JayZuo-MSFT post above. Thank you for your attention.